# How to use Richfaces 4(milestone 4) with maven

Tags: richfaces, seam, jsf-2

I have a query about how to use richfaces with maven. At the moment I am using seam `2.2.1 cr2`, `richfaces 3.3.3` with `jsf2.0.2` with maven.

Please advise how I can use Richfaces 4 - milestone 4 with maven.

1. What repository to use?
2. What entries to add in pom.xml?
3. What dependencies are required?

Unfortunately, how to use *Richfaces 4 maven JBOSS Community* link is down.

Thanks in advance,

B.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the link is http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowtoaddRichFaces4xtomavenbasedproject

Here's google's cached version ;o)

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:c3t49vvjSJ0J:community.jboss.org/wiki/HowtoaddRichFaces4xtomavenbasedproject+richfaces+4+maven&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a